# What element in Magicdraw is equivalent of a controller?

Tags: uml, magic-draw

I have to create a sequence diagram using Magicdraw and I need to add controller elements.

- Entities stand for real world things.
- Interfaces aka boundaries views/models
- Controllers controllers in actual code but what kind of element they are in Magicdraw... no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is a robustness diagram in Magicdraw. Depending on your version it should be on some sort of "Custom diagrams" or "Analysis diagrams" submenu. There you can use the palette to create Boundaries/Entities/Controllers.

Anyway, internally, these elements are just plain old classes with appropriate stereotypes (so you might reach the same result without using the custom diagram by creating classes and applying the stereotypes manually).

Answer (score 0):

late but:

I think Controllers are just classes or interfaces.
the sequence diagrams is a behavioral diagram, then there are instances of a controller-class.
(I would use sequence diagrams little because they are outdated very quickly.)